# Inconsitency in node degree distribution between versions 3.7 and 3.8 in Cytoscape

Tags: cytoscape

The same network, analyzed with the Analyzer in Cytoscape, produces different degree distributions in versions 3.7 and 3.8.

Has anyone noticed this problem?

Distribution with version 3.7

[image: Distribution with version 3.7]

Distribution with version 3.8

[image: Distribution with version 3.8]

The analyzed network is a toy model I use in class. It's a sif file with the following content:

```
1 x 3  1 x 5  2 x 3  2 x 5  2 x 4  3 x 6  3 x 5  3 x 3  4 x 6
```

The version 3.7 produces the correct result.

Comment: Yes, we overhauled the Analyzer code, which hadn't been updated (or properly integrated) for many years.

From your example, I can't tell which one is correct. Can you provide more information on a test case that demonstrates a problem?

Comment: I edited my post to answer your question.

Comment: Excellent. I'll file this as a bug at Cytoscape.org.